Passing password as argument to npm run start command line
I execute npm run start in a .sh command file on a NAS Synology at startup (bash).
But a password is required after this command line, how could i pass it as an argument in my .sh file ?
In the synolofy task scheduler i use :
/bin/bash /volume1/web_packages/nodeapp/run_nodejs.sh
